# ** operator and pow function in PHP 5.6

Tags: php, php-5.6

I have a question regarding ** operator which has appeared in PHP 5.6. 
As far as I understand it, it is used for an exponentiation. 
However, if we want to increase a negative number:

```
var_dump(-2 ** 2);
var_dump(pow(-2, 2));
```

then in the first example the result is -4 and 4 in the second. 
Is it all right? Or this operator acts differently than pow() function?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php `**` has higher precedence than `-`, so it's `-(2**2)`, not `(-2)**2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must be precedence as `var_dump((-2) ** 2);` yields `4`.

So `-2 ** 2` raises `2` to the power of `2` and then makes the result `4` negative.

See [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)